# How does Python handle repr for strings?

Tags: python, repr

I'm trying to emulate Python's repr exactly in Java; this includes the use of single quotes where possible. What method does Python use to determine what sort of quotes it should emit?

Edit: I'm looking for some actual code, somewhere in the web of Python. I've already looked at `Objects/unicodeobject.c` and some of `Objects/strlib/`, but I couldn't find anything besides escape sequences for Unicode.

Comment: Why don't you read the python source?

Comment: On my terminal, the output by repr does not seem to change with respect to the type of quotes used to create the string. `>>> repr("Hello")
"'Hello'"
>>> repr('Hello')
"'Hello'"`

Comment: @simonzack I have. I already extracted what I could from `Objects/unicodeobject.c`.

Comment: @Smac89 It doesn't store quote information, I got that much from the interpreter.

Comment: So you are just wanting to use single quotes to represent strings in Java?

Comment: @Smac89 I'm looking to replicate the behavior of repr exactly in Java. This includes quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it will use single quotes unless it need to use it inside the string.

As show in:

```
print repr("Hello")
print repr('Hello')
print repr("Hell'o")
print repr('Hell"o')
print repr("""Hell'o Worl"o""")
```

Output:

```
'Hello'
'Hello'
"Hell'o" # only one using double quotes
'Hell"o'
'Hell\'o Worl"o' # handles the single quote with a \'
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for an algorithm or similar from the source. I'll update the question.

Comment: @ıɯɐƃoʇǝızuǝʞ IMO your question is clear enough, but some stackoverflow users do not read the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c

```
static PyObject *
unicode_repr(PyObject *unicode)
{ ...
```

unicode_repr in here github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c by the looks of it.

NOTE: I've updated this answer to remove out-of-date info and point to the current repo

Comment: Additionally, latest 3.4 source, I should have said. Oh well, this extremely outdated git mirror will work too. I might be able to track down where `stringobject.c` disappeared to.

Comment: Get the source distro from python.org.

Comment: (for future reference the official mirror is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/))

Comment: Hmm .. not immediately obvious.. PyObject_Repr is calling res = (*v->ob_type->tp_repr)(v);  I can't see something that's obviously the unicode (or string) object type.

Comment: Also, I'm not a C person so this is half guess work on my part.

Comment: So according to Guido "The str() function (now constructor) converts *anything* to a string; tp_str and tp_repr exist to allow objects to customize this." https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2001-September/017590.html  So either the unicode strings in python 3 have their own tp_repr somewhere or they use the default implementation.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at the pypi implementation then?  (I'm not sure exactly how closely pypi and cpython conform at this level).

Answer (score 1):

From what I could extract out of `Objects/byteobject.c` ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/bytesobject.c)), this is the section that does it:

```
quote = '\'';
if (smartquotes && squotes && !dquotes)
    quote = '"';
if (squotes && quote == '\'') {
    if (newsize > PY_SSIZE_T_MAX - squotes)
        goto overflow;
    newsize += squotes;
}
```

So, if there is no double quotes and there is single quotes it uses double quotes, otherwise single quotes.

Comment: Yeah.. I think it depends on whether you want the ascii strings or the unicode strings.  There's a similar block of code in unicode_repr.  And since strings are unicode by default in python3 it's more likely the unicode version is the one you want.